# ghostscript changes orientation of PDF

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I have two single-page PDFs, and want to merge them into a single two-pages PDF. So I ran:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=merged.pdf 1.pdf 2.pdf
```

**Problem**: The result has each page's content rotated 90 degrees clockwise.

[image]

The illustration above shows the problem. I want the two pages to **stay in portrait**. How to do?

Answer (score 2):

Add `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` to your `gs` command.